# jQuery ckeckbox manipulation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a conditional that must check or uncheck an input checkbox, but it doesn't work, and I don't know what to do. I have searched and tried some jquery checkbox manipulation options, but any of them work. With a console log messages I know that the conditional works and the input checkbox is accessible. Please, give me a hand.

```
if(parseInt(permiso_acceso)==1) {
   var valor = $('#permiso_acceso').val();
   console.log('Must be checked '+valor);//It works
   $('#permiso_acceso').attr('checked',true);
} else {
   var valor = $('#permiso_acceso').val();
   console.log('Must be unchecked '+valor);//It works
   $('#permiso_acceso').attr('checked',false);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of `.attr`, use `.prop` jquery method (included in [jquery1.6](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/)).Here is detailed discussion [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

```
if(parseInt(permiso_acceso)==1) {
   var valor = $('#permiso_acceso').val();
   console.log('Must be checked '+valor);//It works
   $('#permiso_acceso').prop('checked', true);
} else {
   var valor = $('#permiso_acceso').val();
   console.log('Must be unchecked '+valor);//It works
   $('#permiso_acceso').prop('checked', false);
}
```

[Try This in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6wVG/108/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

jQuery 1.6+

Use .prop() function:

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

if you want to check if a checkbox is checked or not:

```
$('form #mycheckbox').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

`val()` will always return the `value` property of a `radio` or `checkbox` element, regardless of whether it is ticked or not. The logic of your code is correct.

I would assume the issue is due to the value of `permiso_acceso` not being set to the selected `checkbox` value.

Comment: I used val() just to check that the checkbox was accessible

Answer (score 0):

It happens, because attribute "checked" requeries value "checked", not true or false

Comment: This is incorrect. The `checked` attribute requires no one specific value. The presence of the keyword of the keyword is all that is required, however a value should be assigned for semantic reasons. Whether the value is `checked` or `true` or `foobar` is entirely up the developer.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to check and uncheck a checkbox based on a condition.
check out this fiddle

```
var permiso_acceso = 1;
if(permiso_acceso==1) {
   var valor = $('#permiso_acceso').val();
   console.log('Must be checked '+valor);//It works
   $('#permiso_acceso').attr('checked',true);
} else {
   var valor = $('#permiso_acceso').val();
   console.log('Must be unchecked '+valor);//It works
   $('#permiso_acceso').attr('checked',false);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zhrt3/

try switching the variable permiso_acceso to 1 and 0.

its working

Comment: The conditional was working well. The log message was right. My problem was the method .attr(), once used .prop() all worked like a charm